# Does the subscribe() function execute synchronously?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Just wanted to double check.  [I have this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-authenticated-guard?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauthenticated.guard.ts).

In it there is an `AuthenciatedGuard` with the following block:

```
Auth.isSignedIn().subscribe(yes=>{
  if (yes) {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      return false;
  }
});
return true;
```

So I just want to make sure that the `subscribe()` statement is guaranteed to execute in full and return `false` before we reach the line `return true`.

Comment: This will depend on the Observable returned by isSignedIn()

Comment: You should not rely on it. Why is it a problem? Can you describe why you would need that to be synchronous?

Comment: In this case we need to reach the `return false` statement, before returned true is executed and we need to guarantee that this is the case, otherwise the angular router will not perform the action we are intending for it to perform.

Comment: No, it absolutely won't. In fact there's no point returning from the `.subscribe` callback. If you want to return an observable of boolean, you need to `pipe` not `subscribe`. This only works because you navigate away from the page after you (inaccurately) told the router the user *could* see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not rely on it being synchronous, because it might be now, but not tomorrow.

You can easily return an `Observable<boolean>` or a `Promise<boolean>`, because that is supported by Angular, according to the interface.

```
export class AuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor( private router: Router ) { }


  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

      return Auth.isSignedIn().pipe(map(isAlreadyLoggedIn => {

        if (isAlreadyLoggedIn) {
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          return false;
        }

        return true;
      }));
   }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant Thanks!  I guess I should have looked at the return signature a little more closely :)

Comment: Oh the first time I looked at something like this I had the `!yes` question too.  It's `yes` because we want to deny access to `login` if the use is already signed in.

Comment: Related article: https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/implementing-an-authenticated-guard-in-angular-c9088d745bda

Comment: @Ole I understand. I updated the code to be more clear about what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

You can just return an `Observable<boolean>`:

```
return Auth.isSignedIn().pipe(map(yes=>{
  if (yes) {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      return false;
  } else {
     return true;
  }
}));
```

You can also use a `Promise` return type, for that make your function `async` and use the await converting the `Observable` to a `Promise` :

```
async canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    const yes = await Auth.isSignedIn().toPromise();
    if (yes) {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

An `async` function can only return a `Promise`.

[Running example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-57909492)

Comment: Brilliant Thanks!  I really like how clean it is.  The only thing is that Typescript complains when we put async in front of `canActivate`.  It wants a Global `Promise<T>` returned, which disagrees with the current signature.

Comment: The `canActivate` official signature accepts different return types : https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Comment: Yes I saw that.  Perhaps the `Promise<T>` return part is not global?  Here is a stackblitz that shows the error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-without-authenticated-guard-with-async-return?file=src/app/authenticated.guard.ts

Comment: Sorry the async solution is not meant to be used in Angular Guard. I'm changing my answer.

Comment: I really liked the promise explanation.  I think it's useful for people in general.  Maybe you could include a note about it in the footer of the answer.  Just mention that it can't be used with `canActivate` due to the signature, but it's an novel way of making `subscribe()` synchronous in general.

Comment: @Ole Actually you can just change it to `async canActivate(...): Promise<boolean> {}`. Just leave out the other return types. It just has to satisfy one of them.

Comment: I updated my answer with what Silvermind explained. We actually can use the async with the `canActivate` it just should return a `Promise`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the activator to something like this:

```js
return Auth.isSignedIn().pipe(
    tap(yes => yes && this.router.navigate(['/home'])),
    mapTo(true)
);
```

You should always *assume* that an observable is asynchronous when you can not directly see it's creation. What would you do if `Auth.isSignedIn()` was published by a third-party library?